# Массив c добавлением

Tags: javascript

Хочу добавить несколько элементов в массив. Как я понял, это сделать можно через prompt. (других вариантов пока не нашел)

```
var array = [] // создаю пустой массив
var pushed = array.push(prompt("введите что-то в массив")) //вношу что-то в массив
document.write(array) //вывожу массив
```

Но при таком коде я добавляю только одно значение. пробовал через цикл - но тогда не могу выйти с него.
А хотелось бы добавлять значения, и если отмена, выход и все элементы сохраняются.

Comment: Это где такие `prompt`, `alert`, `document.write` вы откапываете?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не рекомендовал бы использовать prompt, но если его, то:

```js
let array = [];
let a = null;
while(a = window.prompt('Введите что-нибудь')){
  array.push(a);
}
console.log(array);
```

Попытка сделать без `prompt`, кнопку `Добавить` можно игнорировать, нажимая на `Enter`))

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let output = document.getElementById('output');
let remove = document.getElementById('remove');
let array = [];
let addToArray = e => {
  array.push(e.target.value);
  e.target.value = '';
  output.innerHTML = array.join(`<br>`);
}

let removeFromArray = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  array = [];
  output.innerHTML = '';
}

input.addEventListener('change', addToArray);
remove.addEventListener('click', removeFromArray);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<hr>
<input type="submit" value="Добавить">
<button id="remove">Удалить всё</button>
<hr>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В вопросе вы уже упомянули метод push. Именно им и нужно пользоваться для добавления элементов в массив. Чтобы добавить несколько элементов в массив за один раз вы можете в метод push передать не одно значение, а несколько, разделив их запятой. Думаю вам всё станет понятно из приведённого ниже примера.

```js
let myArr = [1,2,3];
myArr.push(4,5,6)
console.log(myArr) // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Если вы хотите добавить несколько значений в массив именно из диалогового окна prompt, то можно сделать так:

```js
let myArr = [1,2,3];
myArr.push(...prompt('Введите значения через пробел').split(' '));
console.log(myArr)
```

Comment: при отмене prompt вернет null и все упадет

Comment: @Grundy Я только подал идею. Естественно можно добавить проверки, в том числе на тот же null.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй через [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) оператор.

```js
let a = window.prompt('Введите что-нибудь').split(', ') // asd, bfg 
let array = []
array = [...array, ...a]
console.log(array)
```